# Custom Pixi.js filter in TypeScript, with secondary texture uniform

Tags: typescript, fragment-shader, pixi.js

My goal is to apply a filter to an object which takes a smaller resolution texture as a uniform input and have it appear on the object. My attempt isn't displaying the texture or throwing errors.

My filter:

```
class MyFilter extends PIXI.Filter {
  constructor(uniforms) {
    super(null, `
      precision mediump float;

      varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
      uniform sampler2D uSampler;
      uniform sampler2D uTexture;

      void main {
        //vec4 diffuseColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);
        vec4 tex = texture2D(uTexture, vTextureCoord);

        gl_FragColor = vec4(tex.r, tex.g, tex.b, 1.0);
      }
    `, {});
  }
}
```

The implementation

```
let renderer = new PIXI.WebGLRenderer(...);

let g = new PIXI.Graphics();
g.beginFill(0x333333);
g.drawRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
g.endFill();

let texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/33073/landscape.jpg");

let myFilter = new MyFilter();
myFilter.uniforms['uTexture'] = texture;
g.filters = [myFilter];

renderer.render(g);
```

I found a working javascript example:
https://jsfiddle.net/nu2k4txr/10/

I'm guessing that the issue is to do with my implementation of the filter, but I can't figure it out and would appreciate any help.

I couldn't figure out how to make a TypeScript pixi.js jsFiddle example. Bonus points for this.

Comment: I got something working without extending the class. I'm claiming the bonus points for myself with this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wzz7agmt/1/